# What is the component in the schematic below?

Tags: identification

I have a problem with identifying components labeled by P1, P2 and so on.
The schematic is described as anticoincidence circuit in Polish (I think it's the closest translation), however searching online does not show results similar to the circuit below.

[image: Anticoincidence circuit (?)]

Answer (score 3):

The pulse inside the symbols indicates that they are monostables.

Comment: Note that P4 and P5 are triggered on the falling edges of P1 and P2, respectively, and that P3 is triggered if there's any overlap between P1 and P2 at all. Therefore, t2 must be greater than the sum of t1 and t3 in order to guarantee inhibiting the output pulses when a coincidence occurs.

Comment: An excellent addition, Dave.